# Do I need a media server if I'm going to deploy a RTMFP video/audio streaming?

Tags: flash, rtmfp

I have some questions, please answer me.

Basically I want to develop something like Livestream / Ustream web app. I want to learn how to develop something like that.. But I have no experience in developing flash applications, so im looking for answers before i dive in.

i have read about RTMFP, and I found out that it is a peer-to-peer video/audio streaming technology, so i'm confused if i need to have a media server like adobe flash media server to stream live videos.

I read that RTMFP doesn't consume my bandwidth because it is a peer to peer technology, is that true? If it is then this is really too good to be true, but i know that when a product is too good to be true then it must have many disadvantages. please tell me the disadvantages for using RTMFP for a Livestream / Ustream app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need [Adobe FMS](http://www.adobe.com/go/tryflashmediaserver/) for RTMFP, there is a free dev. edition allowing 10 simultaneous connections and commercial use.

The production version (including the Amazon edition) is quite costly though... so maybe you should check their prices before trying to develop something RTMFP-capable.

Also there is a free Red5 server, but it doesn't support RTMFP yet, only RTMP(T)

Answer (score 5):

You can combine ffmpeg, red5 and Cumulus and you pretty much get the functionality of a FMS w/o the hefty fees. i have a functional CentOS 6 cloud instance that runs a LAMP + Cumulus+ Red5 1.0 RC + ffmpeg (for post recording processing) that works like a charm for testing - haven't tested in production yet but with an expandable server instance (cloud) you should be fine and grow as needed - i'm using PerfectIP for inexpensive hosting and testing but in production go to Amazon's AWS

Cumulus/OpenRTMFP is a bit tricky to setup on Cent OS 6 but not too much and once ON it stays on - my instance has not been rebooted for 6 mo and the RTMFP still introduces peers and maintains connections perfectly.

legal - no idea i suspect adobe has some patents pending on the RTMFP but considering the great job the creators of Cumulus did, i think adobe will be tolerant towards an Open Source technology utilizing the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Cumulus/OpenRTMFP seems to be an alternative to FMS.

But has someone experience with this server? And is it legal?